# what is the different between "plt.gca().legend()" and "plt.legend()" in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

what is the different between "plt.gca().legend()" and "plt.legend()"  ? I want to add labels in my picture, and then I found these two functions online, but don't know when to use which function is appropriate? Can anyone help me explain in simple terms?

Comment: I don't think there is any.

Comment: The best approach would be using the [`object-oriented interface`](https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/).   With `plt.gca().legend()` you are mixing the object-oriented interface with the old pyplot interface.  Such mix is only adequate when you are using the pyplot interface for everything and want to use new functions that only exist in the object-oriented interface (e.g. `ax.tick_params(....)`).

Comment: just to add, `gca()` gives you the current axes